# When installing elasticsearch and running the Searchkick's reindex command, do I need to be inside the master branch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Should I be inside the master branch when installing Elasticsearch and running the `rake searchkick:reindex` command?

Because all the tutorials I found are inside the master branch, but when I'm adding a feature to my app, I always checkout on other branch and just merge it if the feature works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `elasticsearch` will be installed in your system so it will have no relation with your git branch. The things which will have relation with your git branch is the `configuration` of your `elasticsearch` server which can be defined different in different branches. And the other things which will matter while running `rake searchkick:reindex` is your `search_data` method.

Suppose in your `master` branch your `search_data` method is like this:

```
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    department_name: department.name
  }
end
```

And now you checkout to new branch and make changes in this method:

```
def search_data
  {
    name: name,
    department_name: department.name,
    on_sale: sale_price.present?
  }
end
```

So you will have to run a `reindex` so the new data has been indexed in the elasticsearch. And this(reindexed data) is also not dependent on the branch but what should be reindexed is dependent on the branch.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what you mean is both the installation of Elasticsearch and the `reindex` is not dependent on branch and I can do the installation and the `reindex` in any branch, am I right?

Comment: Exactly. But what should be `reindexed` is dependent on branch. So as I have given you an example above if you do something like that then you might face exception until you `reindex`.